# ModuleNotFoundError when running Python script in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, flask, pip, anaconda

I am trying to run the following Flask app on Anaconda Prompt

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, abort
import os
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField
from werkzeug import secure_filename


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.run(debug=True)

@app.route('/')
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
if request.method == 'POST':
    return render_template('map.html')
else:
    return render_template('map.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=4000)
```

This results in the following error:

```
(C:\Users\jgpfi_000\Anaconda3) 
C:\Users\jgpfi_000\Documents\housescrapeapp>py app_index.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "app_index.py", line 3, in <module>
        from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, abort
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

I have already installed the module through PIP.

I have tried appending the PATH of the script location using:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\jgpfi_000\Documents\housescrapeapp\app_index.py')
```

but the same error still occurs.

Comment: What is the output of `conda list`?

Comment: flask is on the list: `flask                     0.12.2                   py36_0
flask-cors                3.0.2                    py36_0` @darthbith

Comment: What if you run `python app_index.py` instead of `py app_index.py`?

Comment: Yes that fixed it after uninstalling python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by uninstalling Python 3.7 and simply running `python app_index.py` in anaconda prompt

Answer (score 0):

There are usually two versions of Python installed, 2.x and 3.x versions.

If you use `pip`, the 2.x version's site library will be updated, in order to install the required package with the 3.x version, you can use this:

```
python -m pip install flask
```